# How can I get videos link from instagram in android using webview

Tags: javascript, android, html, web-scraping

Basically i want to get video link when i click on it i use the below code but this is not working for me.

mWebView.webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {

```
        override fun onPageFinished(view: WebView?, url: String?) {
            this@MainActivity.mWebView.loadUrl(
                "javascript:(function () { " +
                        "var el = document.getElementsByClassName ('_2c9v _53mv')" +
                        "var elu = document.getElementsByClassName ('PyenC')" +
                        "for(var i=0;i<el.length; i++){" +
                        "elu[i].style.display ='none';" +
                        "el[i].setAttribute('onclick', 'insta.processVideo(\"'+el[i].src+'\");');" +
                        "}}})()"
            )
            progress.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
            super.onPageFinished(view, url)
        }

        override fun onPageStarted(view: WebView?, url: String?, favicon: Bitmap?) {
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon)
        }

        override fun onLoadResource(view: WebView?, url: String?) {
            this@MainActivity.mWebView.loadUrl(
                "javascript:(function prepareVideo() { " +
                        "var el = document.getElementsByClassName ('_2c9v _53mv')" +
                        "var elu = document.getElementsByClassName ('PyenC')" +
                        "for(var i=0;i<el.length; i++){" +
                        "elu[i].style.display ='none';" +
                        "el[i].setAttribute('onclick', 'insta.processVideo(\"'+el[i].src+'\");');" +
                        "}}})()"
            )
            this@MainActivity.mWebView.loadUrl("javascript:( window.onload=prepareVideo)()")
        }
    }
    mWebView.loadUrl("https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/")

}
```